# How to return y value from vector 3 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector, return

I have a vector 3 (x,y,z) 1D dynamic array full of vertex positions.

How would I return the y value at a given x and z coordinate?

Edit:: Sorry about the lack of detail.

I am using c++, compiling in Visual Studio 2008.
The vector is a vector class storing 3 float values defining an x, y and z variable, it is used for position.

It's like Vector3 *array;

array = new Vector3[100];

Lots of positional values are added to the array.

When you access a member of the array for a specific value it's like

array[0].y

But I want to find a the y value that corresponds to a specific x and z

like

GetY(float x, float z)

...

return y;

Comment: I am using c++ and i'm compiling with Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Is vector3 a class/struct or a `std::vector`?  Your question may need more details to get a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have something like

```
struct Vec3D{
  float x, y, z;
};

Vec3D vec3d_arr[20];
```

Then, to get what you want, you'll need to iterate over the array.

```
float GetYforXZ(Vec3D* arr, unsigned int length, float x_val, float z_val){
  for(unsigned i=0; i < length; ++i){
    if(arr[i].x == x_val && arr[i].z == z_val)
      return arr[i].y;
  }
}

int main(){
  Vec3D arr[20];

  // init arr

  float y = GetYforXZ(arr,20,15.4f,23.3f);
}
```

---

**Edit**: On your comment:

```
#include <map>
#include <math>
using namespace std;

struct Vec3D{
  float x, y, z;
};

const float float_eps = 1e-5;

struct float_wrapper{
    float _value;

    float_wrapper()
        : _value(0.0f) {}

    float_wrapper& operator=(float f){
        _value = f;
        return *this;
    }

    operator float() const{
        return _value;
    }
};

bool operator==(float_wrapper const& lhs, float_wrapper const& rhs){
    float tmp = fabs(lhs._value - rhs._value);
    return tmp < float_eps && tmp >= 0;
}

bool operator<(float_wrapper const& lhs, float_wrapper const& rhs){
    return lhs._value < rhs._value;
}

typedef map< float_wrapper,float_wrapper > zy_map;
typedef map< float_wrapper,zy_map > xzy_map;

void init_vertex_mapping(xzy_map& a_map, Vec3D* arr, size_t length){
  for(size_t i=0; i < length; ++i){
    Vec3D& vertex = arr[i];
    zy_map& zy = a_map[vertex.x];
    zy[vertex.z] = vertex.y;
  }
}

int main(){
  xzy_map vertex_map;
  Vec3D vertex_array[100] = { {0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{-3.14f,42.0f,-13.37f},{0,0,0} };

  init_vertex_mapping(vertex_map, vertex_array, 100);

  float y = vertex_map[-3.14f][-13.37f];
}
```

Though a problem that I forgot is the inaccuracy of `float`s, so maybe you get problems with the map. Comment back if you do. :)

---

**Edit**:
Added a more safe version, employing a `float_wrapper`.

Comment: Yes Xeo that's the sort of thing i'm after. Is that the only way to do it though because depending on the array size you could have to cycle through a great number of locations before I find what i'm looking for?

Comment: @Curious: You could try a `map<float,map<float,float>` to map from x and z to y, and get it like `float y = xz_map[3.14f][13.37f]`, but you'd need to fill it first, aka you need to iterate over the array at least once. Don't know if that works for you. :/

Comment: Iterating through it once in the loading phase should be no bother, it was more doing it every time I wanted a coordinate that was the issue. I'm not very familiar with the technique you mentioned could you point me towards some literature on map?

Comment: @Curious: Also, are you allowed to sort the array? I suppose not, because normally vertex values are in a certain order to enable faster rendering and stuff.

Comment: @Curious: Well, that's the problem I talked about with the inaccuracy of floats. Since `std::map` checks with `operator==` if the value was found, it won't find the correct one sometimes / all of the times. Lemme edit that.

Comment: It actualy seems like the values are only incorrect with negative x and z coordinates

Comment: @Curious: Can you show me some example values so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry. It's late I think i'm being silly here. I now don't think there is a problem at all and i'm using values that don't exist in the array. I'll take a closer look at it, thanks for your help. =P

Comment: @Curious: See my edit anyways, won't do any harm to provide a comparision save wrapper.

Comment: You are hereby awarded a beer

Answer (score 1):

You just have to search your array for the vector element with the given x and z coordinates and the get this element's corresponding y value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, that your vector is something like `float vector[3];` then `vector[1]` references the second value in the array, said your Y coordinate of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

How do you like this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Vector3
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    enum SearchType
    {
        XY, YZ, XZ
    };

    static SearchType searchType;

    Vector3(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0)
        : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {
    }

    bool operator == (const Vector3 & vec)
    {
        switch(searchType)
        {
            case XY: return (x == vec.x) && (y == vec.y);
            case YZ: return (y == vec.y) && (z == vec.z);
            case XZ: return (x == vec.x) && (z == vec.z);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Vector3::SearchType Vector3::searchType = XY;

int main()
{
    Vector3 * array = new Vector3 [100];

    array[57].x = 5;
    array[57].y = 100;
    array[57].z = 6;

    Vector3::searchType = Vector3::XZ; // Specify find type as "XZ"
    Vector3 * vec = std::find(array, array+100, Vector3(5,0,6));

    if (vec != array+100)
    {
        cout << "Value for X == 5 and Z == 6 is in "
             << (vec-array) << " item and it eq " << (*vec).y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the setup you provided not work with negative floating point values?

Comment: Sorry for this bug. Just use return fabs(a-b) <= eps; in float_eq static method.

Answer (score -1):

Please, **NEVER EVER** perform a search on an unsorted array/vector. Even if it has only 100 elements today, it might become 100000 tomorrow. Take a look at [Wiki Sorting Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), some of them are easy to understand and implement. Then look at [Wiki Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). I would start with quick sort, which also gives you a good idea how binary search works.
Believe me, you will thank me later.

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted you, but I agree with the sentiment. It depends on the problem at hand -- if you only ever do one search for an element, there's no point doing an Omega(n lg n) sort in order to then do an O(lg n) search. The fact that your search is now O(lg n) instead of O(n) is outweighed by the time you wasted sorting the array. If you're doing lots of searches, then sorting makes more sense.

Comment: i agree on this. Depends on the size of the problem. Many better complexity searches needs more overhead, and thus becomes slower for small input compared to the higher time complexity algos for small input.

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: You have valid arguments for one search, no arguing here. It's also valid for prototyping, demos, lots other things. But when I hear word "search" I immediately thinking "sort", I was raised this way

Comment: I give up! After looking at @k06a's beautifully written code I just realized how secondary all this sorting business can be...

Comment: Thank you for the information it looks like it will make a good read. From a precursory glance it looks like it would provide little improvement here as the data is not necessarily stored as a natural grid and may contain gaps. Without properly researching I can't be sure if my observation is correct. I will endevour to learn about sorting algorithms and binary searches as soon as posisble. Once again thank you